# HTOP understanding

Tags: 32-bit, memory-usage, htop

Sorry new to linux/ubuntu. I have read through a bunch of `htop` posts here, but I just wanted to clarify what the values mean. I run a 32-bit program, and my understanding is that roughly 4.2 is the max amount of memory this application can use. If I go over that, I will get a calloc error.

When looking at `htop`, am I looking at the `virt` or the `res` amount to see when it's getting close to that 4gb limit?

[image: htop image]

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [`htop` man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/htop.1.html):

> M_RESIDENT (RES)
>
> The resident set size (text + data + stack) of the process  (i.e.  the  size  of  the process's used physical memory).
>
> M_SIZE (VIRT)
>
> The size of the virtual memory of the process.

However, `RES` just shows that - the physical memory, it doesn't mean in any way that the 32-bit binary process will be limited to 4 GB **in total**, and in fact if you have [Physical Address Extension enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488828/am-i-using-more-than-4-gb-on-my-32-bit-system) the process could use more than that. Physically, yes, 2<sup>32</sup> addresses means 4GB of physical RAM. As per [Gilles's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34994/85039) (with my emphasis):

> A 32-bit Linux kernel can only execute 32-bit processes. Depending on the kernel compilation options, each process can only allocate 1GB, 2GB or 3GB of memory (the rest is reserved for the kernel when it's processing system calls). *This is an amount of virtual memory, unrelated to any breakdown between RAM, swap, and mmapped files.*

Also according to an [answer by Ramesh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/142668/85039) on Unix & Linux site, a process can have large quantities of memory allocated:

> The most that the *process* can *address* is 4GB. You are potentially confusing memory with address space. **A process can have more memory than address space.** That is *perfectly legal* and *quite common in video processing and other memory intensive applications.* A process can be allocated dozens of GB of memory and swap it into and out of the address space at will. Only 2 GB can go into the user address space at a time.
>
> If you have a four-car garage at your house, you can still own fifty cars. You just can't keep them all in your garage. You have to have auxiliary storage somewhere else to store at least 46 of them; which cars you keep in your garage and which ones you keep in the parking lot down the street is up to you.

Corroborated with [Breakthrough's answer](https://superuser.com/a/561101/418028):

> In terms of an address being "valid", each process has it's own unique address space (thus implementing a virtual memory scheme), so any address is technically valid. Remember, a process can allocate more memory than is physically available.
>
> ...
>
> A virtual address for a given process is mapped to some physical storage hardware (RAM, disk, etc...), but the mapping is done at run-time by the operating system & MMU.

Of course, [address space being 4GB implies pointers still being 32-bit](http://PAE%20is%20an%20extension%20of%20the%20hardware's%20address%20bus,%20and%20some%20page%20table%20modifications%20to%20handle%20that.%20It%20doesn't%20change%20the%20fact%20that%20a%20pointer%20is%20still%2032%20bits,%20limiting%20you%20to%204G%20of%20address%20space%20in%20a%20single%20process.).

---

Additionally Linux kernel has [Out Of Memory Killer/Manager](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html), which will clean up and free up memory. In other words, don't stress out about the 4GB limit, if you're worried about the process memory overall.

If by contrast we're talking about allocating 4 GB **in your code**, then according to a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37991185/3701431) `malloc()` syscall will be in fact limited to 4 GB of allocations. But [you can do more than one `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31587436/3701431) requesting more than 4GB in total (though I'm not entirely sure how that works out with the physical limit).

Other interesting readings:

- [What is RSS and VSZ in Linux memory management](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7880784/3701431)
- [In Linux, how to tell how much memory processes are using?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3853655/3701431)

Comment: Thanks, the 4GB is definitely a real thing for me, and we had a calloc error last night. Maybe it was due to something else. Will look into it more. Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension#Design suggests that your statement is wrong and the 4GB limit still applies to each individual process on PAE systems. The OS can just address more physical memory in total, but software still only has 32 bit wide address pointers, resulting in 2^32 = 4GB maximum memory usage per process.

Comment: @ByteCommander that's what I thought it was, so if RES is under 4GB, then I am good, if it goes over, I'm done?

Comment: Not sure about that, but I don't think either value can go over 4GB.

Comment: @ByteCommander see that's the biggest question I have because I'm sitting around 3gb VIRT right now but i did get to 4gb and it crashed. Working on porting to 64bit now but until then.

Comment: @ByteCommander I've addressed that. Physically, yes - we're not going to get above 4 GB physical memory. Software-wise, it's quite possible to request/allocate more than that. Links provided as well.

Comment: @Jeff  OK, let's back up a little bit and maybe clarify what you're asking in this question ( and maybe edit that into the question itself). Can application use more than 4GB memory ? Yes. Can more than 4 GB of RAM be used  if you only have 4 GB RAM installed ?  No, physically not possible and some will be reserved by kernel. Can a process use more memory in total if you have only 4GB of RAM ? Yes, with PAE.  What causes the crash ? Lots of possible options, it's not limited to just RES memory growing large, although it's likely.

Comment: Also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1440020 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2798357

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyyI have 32GB of ram on this server. I'm running a chroot 32 bit kernel so I can run a 32 bit app. It's currently sitting at 3292M Virt and 2049M Res. 6.4% of memory.